# How do I get Material-UI SpeedDialAction onClick events to fire when SpeedDial is open on click only (not hover)

Tags: javascript, material-ui

For some reason, when I change material-ui `<SpeedDial>` to remove the prop `onMouseEnter={handleOpen}` so that the speed dial only opens upon clicking the FAB instead of on hover, the `onClick` event in `<SpeedDialAction>` does not get triggered when I click a speed dial menu item. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

```
  return (
    <SpeedDial
      ariaLabel="Add"
      className={classes.root}
      icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
      onClick={handleClick}
      onClose={handleClose}
      onBlur={handleClose}
      // onMouseEnter={handleOpen}
      // onMouseLeave={handleClose}
      open={open}
      direction={mobile ? 'up' : 'down'}
    >
      {actions.map(action => (
        <SpeedDialAction
          key={action.name}
          icon={action.icon}
          tooltipTitle={action.name}
          tooltipOpen
          classes={{ staticTooltipLabel: classes.staticTooltipLabel }}
          onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('x');
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </SpeedDial>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `preventDefault` will not cause the `click` event to not propagate to the parent element (which from what I understand is what you are trying to get).

You should use the `stopPropagation` instead:

```
<SpeedDial
  ariaLabel="Add"
  className={classes.SpeedDial}
  icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
  onClick={handleClick}
  open={open}
>
  {actions.map(action => (
    <SpeedDialAction
      key={action.name}
      icon={action.icon}
      tooltipTitle={action.name}
      tooltipOpen
      onClick={e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("x");
      }}
    />
  ))}
</SpeedDial>
```

Check the following example: https://codesandbox.io/s/speeddial-open-on-click-rleg5?file=/demo.js

Comment: This got it working, but turns out it was a side-effect of `onBlur={handleClose}`. When I took this out, events started propogating properly (even with `e.preventDefault()`)

Answer (score 0):

I end up setting the `onclick` handler **onto the `icon`** instead

- (more precisely, the **parent `<button>` (the `blue circle`)** of the `icon` 
  otherwise, you have to click at the *exact position* of `icon`, instead of the `blue circle`
- *-- but this feels hacky...* 
  *-- wish MaterialUi provides better Api for `SpeedDial` for this...*)

code:

- @watch for this part:

  ```
          <SpeedDialIcon
            ref={React.useCallback((elt: HTMLElement | null | any) => {
              if (elt instanceof HTMLElement) {
                if (elt.parentElement instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
                  elt.parentElement.onclick = () => set_show((show) => !show);
  ```
- full code:

  ```
  const PanelVisbilityController: React.FC<{
    set_show_MediaStreamLocalSelfGridPanel_rst: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
    set_show_LobbyUserListPanel_rst: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
    set_show_VideoConnectionControlPanel_rst: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
    set_show_TextChat_rst: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
    set_show_DebugPanel_rst: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  }> = React.memo(({ set_show_MediaStreamLocalSelfGridPanel_rst, set_show_LobbyUserListPanel_rst, set_show_VideoConnectionControlPanel_rst, set_show_TextChat_rst, set_show_DebugPanel_rst }) => {
    const [show, set_show] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
    // reversed order ...
    const actions = [
      { icon: <VideoLibraryIcon />,       name: 'MediaStream',        onClick: () => set_show_MediaStreamLocalSelfGridPanel_rst(show => !show) },
      { icon: <VideoChatIcon />,          name: 'ConnectionAnchor',   onClick: () => { console.log('// Do nothing')} },
      { icon: <VideoCameraFrontIcon />,   name: 'LobbyUserList',      onClick: () => set_show_LobbyUserListPanel_rst(show => !show) },
      { icon: <VideogameAssetOutlined  />,name: 'ControlPanel',       onClick: () => set_show_VideoConnectionControlPanel_rst(show => !show) },
      { icon: <ChatIcon />,               name: 'TextChat',           onClick: () => set_show_TextChat_rst(show => !show) },
      { icon: <BugReportIcon />,          name: 'DebugPanel',         onClick: () => set_show_DebugPanel_rst(show => !show) },
    ]; // prettier-ignore
    return (
      <SpeedDial
        ariaLabel="SpeedDial PanelVisbilityController"
        sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 16, right: 16 }}
        icon={
          <SpeedDialIcon
            ref={React.useCallback((elt: HTMLElement | null | any) => {
              if (elt instanceof HTMLElement) {
                if (elt.parentElement instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
                  elt.parentElement.onclick = () => set_show((show) => !show);
                } else {
                  console.warn('internal structure of material-ui SpeedDialIcon is changed, hack doesnt work, fall back to default handling');
                  elt.onclick = () => set_show((show) => !show);
                }
              } else if (elt === null) {
                // @do_nothing react thing ... elt is null
              } else {
                // console.log(typeof elt);
                // console.log(elt.constructor.name);
                console.error('I may use the ref wrong in react,, to access to the dom element...');
              }
            }, [])}
            // onClick={() => set_show((show) => !show)}
          />
        }
        open={show}
      >
        {actions.reverse().map((action) => (
          <SpeedDialAction
            key={action.name}
            icon={action.icon}
            tooltipTitle={action.name}
            onClick={(ev) => {
              // ;not_good, clicking the icon inside also triggers; () => set_show((show) => !show);
              // ;not_good, clicking the blank region also triggers; []
              // ;not_good, clicking the blank region also triggers; You should use the stopPropagation instead:
              // ;not_good, clicking the blank region also triggers; <>
              // ;not_good, clicking the blank region also triggers; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649335/how-do-i-get-material-ui-speeddialaction-onclick-events-to-fire-when-speeddial-i
              // ;not_good, clicking the blank region also triggers; ev.stopPropagation();
              action.onClick();
            }}
            // open={false}
          />
        ))}
      </SpeedDial>
    );
  });
  ```

---

In another answer post. 
The use of `e.stopPropagation();` works a bit, 
but it has the problem of `clicking the blank region also triggers` -- its not limited to only the `blue circle` button.